# Arch linux; Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is truncated

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade

After upgrading my whole system yesterday

```
pacman -Syu
```

im facing the following error at boot

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: ZSTD-compressed data is truncated
/init: line 6: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: Textfile busy

A password is required to access the volgroup0 volume:
Enter the passphrase for /dev/sb3:
```

whenever i try to put my passphrase it doesnt do anything and i have to manually shutdown my laptop

**What i think could have caused this**

a week or so ago i installed the zen kernel but it gave me some errors and i forgot to uninstall it.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that your `/boot` partition is completely full, and when you last updated the kernel `mkniticpio` tried to generate new images, but didn't have enough space, and you were left with a bad (truncated) initramfs.

The solution would be to chroot into your filesystem with an Arch Linux LiveUSB, clean up `/boot` of any unneeded files, and then manually regenerate the initramfs.

Detailed step by step:

- First, boot an Arch Linux LiveUSB.
- Identify your `/` and `/boot` partitions with `fdisk -l`
- Mount the root partition: `mount /dev/{rootpartition} /mnt/`
- Mount `/boot` into your root partition: `mount /dev/{bootpartition} /mnt/boot`
- Chroot into your system: `arch-chroot /mnt`
- Remove existing `initramfs` images, and any unnecessary `vmlinuz` kernels from `/boot/`.
- Regenerate the initramfs with `mkinitcpio -P`

Pay attention to the output of the last command. If you're getting `bsdtar` errors this likely means `/boot` is still full. You can use `df -h /boot` to check disk usage.

If that's the case, you can either increase the size of `/boot`, or check how the initramfs is being generated in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, and remove any modules you don't need from your configuration. In particular, if you're on NVIDIA, you may wish to remove the modules listed in [this section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA#Early_loading) if you're not facing display issues.

Comment: Is `{rootpartition}` something like `/dev/sda1`? And is the boot partition `/dev/sda1/boot`? Sorry, I'm just new to this. And what would any of this be different on ubuntu? I assume there's a different command to `arch-chroot`.

Comment: @Clara you saved me from a lot of trouble. Thank you very much for your detailed passages.